# Is CSS indentation just for readability?

Tags: css, sass

I was reading this from the SCSS docs:

> Nested Rules
>
> Sass allows CSS rules to be nested within one another. The inner rule
>   then only applies within the outer rule’s selector. For example:

```
 #main p {   color: #00ff00;   width: 97%;

   .redbox {
     background-color: #ff0000;
     color: #000000;   } }
```

> is compiled to:

```
 #main p {   
      color: #00ff00;   width: 97%; }   
      #main p .redbox {
         background-color: #ff0000;
         color: #000000; }
```

Is the bottom code block just standard CSS? Is the indentation necessary? Or is it just convention to write it this way in CSS files?

Comment: No, indentation is not necessary. You could write all of your CSS without any linebreaks. Just look at a minified CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just convention, CSS ignores the whitespaces. Once SCSS is compiled, it's just standard CSS.